# Blacklisting IP in DNS lookup without compromising client-side load-balancing

Tags: dns, load-balancing

I would like to do DNS lookup on a FQDN s.t.:

- A single IP is returned based on the weights in the DNS SRV records (if any)
- Blacklisted IP are taken out of the equation and never returned

The purpose of that is to do some circuit breaking at a DNS level to temporarily block certain IP's if they are pointing to bad hosts.

I already did some search on Google but couldn't find much discussion on this topic. I'd imagine this should be a solved problem given it can come up quite a bit.

With that said, I wonder if there's an open source library that does this or if this problem is solved in some other way.

Comment: It is unclear what are you trying to achieve: blacklisted where and by whom, what are "bad hosts", do you want this in DNS server or on client side?

Comment: Bad hosts is something to be determined in the implementation level (e.g. too many timeouts, high average latency of response). DNS is client-side